# Кодом расчёта аннуитетных платежей не проходит тесты

Tags: python

```
r = int(input())
p = int(input())
m = int(input())
i = (p/100)/12
k = (i*(i+1)**m)/((i+1)**m-1)
print(k*r*m-r)
```

в чём проблема кода? Почему он не прошёл некоторые тесты на **silvertests**?

Comment: На код ревью видимо зарежектили

Answer (score 1):

почему формула может не пройти

1. вводят неверные значения - например треш из букв или отрицательные значения, а код этой ситуации никак не отрабатывает
2. вводят `p = 0` или `m = 0`, что вызывает деление на 0
3. вводят числа с плавающей запятой, а вы их принимаете как целочисленные, в результате будут неправильные вычисления

> в чём проблемма кода? Почему он не прошёл некоторые тесты на silvertests?

я склоняюсь к 3)

Comment: Да не, там формула кривая просто)

Comment: ну коэффициент аннуитета вроде как правильный, а дальше не смотрел :)

Comment: спасибо, там оказывается p не int а float

Answer (score 0):

Если финальный результат - аннуитетный платёж, то он не корректен

```
r = 1_000_000
p = 10
m = 12
i = (p/100)/12

k = (i*(i+1)**m)/((i+1)**m-1)
print(f'your={k*r*m-r}; correct={r*i / (1-(1+i)**(-m))}')
```

> your=54990.64676011889; correct=87915.88723000987